# changing the src of the images on a webpage using jquery according to screen resolution

Tags: jquery

i am working on a plugin where the user enters the image for laptop or mobile and then acocording to that the src changes.
now i have done this
a simple image element is added

```
<img src="#" data-tablet="img/xl.jpg" data-laptop="img/xllaptop.jpg" >
<img  src="#" data-tablet="img/x2.jpg" data-laptop="img/x2laptop.jpg" >
```

Now i have done this using javascript

```
    var  currentWindowSize = $window.width();
    if (currentWindowSize <640) 
{
        $(img).attr("src","source should come from the data-attribute");
    }
    if (currentWindowSize >640) 
{
        $(img).attr("src","source should come from the data-attribute");
    }
```

Now the problem is it will change the attributes of all the images.
How can i do something that the image with the same data attributes changes, 
**I need it to be done without giving any Id or classes.** 
thanks.
**Source should come from data attribute like data-tablet with tablet path etc..**
( Can i use something like this keyword).
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var  currentWindowSize = $(window).width();

if (currentWindowSize <= 640) {
    $('img').each(
        function(){
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-tablet"));

     });

} else if (currentWindowSize > 640) {
   $('img').each(
    function(){
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-desktop"));

    });
};
```